# How to backtest a strategy with irregular in-out signal?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, backtesting, quantitative, quants

Hi I'm currently backtesting an event-driven strategies. Unlike factor strategy which has a regular rebalancing interval, event-driven strategy is conducted whenever there is an event.
Since we do not know how many signals would pop up in the future in the past timepoint, I defined unit position size per one in-out betting.

I think there can be 2 possible ways to backtest such strategy.

1. (I think this would be a common case) Align every event-driven signal into one single timeline and check the mean return of the event. For example, if I want to test buyback event driven strategy, regardless of the announcement of the buyback event, set announcement date as 0 and last holding moment as 20 (1-month holding strategy, for example). And average the returns per day and check how long does buyback alpha persist from the announcement date.
2. (This is the case where I get confused) I want to calculate cumulative return of this strategy.  (Final amount of money I can earn by conducting this strategy) However, since there is no fixed seed money at the very first time of the backtest, how can I calculate the return?
   Currently, I'm tracking

- unrealized return(evaluated return)
- realized return
- unit position price(number of currently held position * unit position size)
- unit position price averaged

and final return is calculated as (unrealized return + realized return) / unit position price averaged.
But is it right way to calculate cumulative return of such strategy? How can I backtest cumulative return of a strategy without fixed seed money but flexible in-out position?

Answer (score 1):

1. Typically events like those last a quarter or some variable time period. Then your position may get stop lossed half way through. So instead of forcing an alignment, just simulate a portfolio.
2. Your strategy must start with some seed money, otherwise how can you calculate a return or do a trade? You start with some capital, and then simulate daily NAVs for your strategy and then link the daily returns to create a backyesr

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For the 2nd answer, I mean if I started with a seed amount of 100 then I started betting "10" per position, how should I deal with the 11th position if it is realized? |
If I really want to know 'expected return per betting of the strategy", I'm curious whether such methodology is still available

Comment: By the way, this is how it’s done in real trading. If you want to make a new position, your code has to either sell one or resize them to fit (or borrow). Dealing with real world constraints is very important to developing a successful backtest